# If statement does not detect string or doesn't take action

Tags: python, python-3.6

I wanted to make a bot that plays Rock, Paper, Scissors with the player.
But every time I try to run the script, and type in `Stein` (German for rock),
the if statement doesn't detect it or doesn't take any action.

Here's my code so far:

```
import random
import time

print("Anfangs Buchstaben immer groß schreiben!")

time.sleep(2)

outcomes2 = ("Stein")

Runde = 0

while True:

 Player = input("Deine Wahl: ")

 for i in range(1):
    outcomes = print(random.choice(outcomes2))

 if outcomes == Player:
    print("draw")
    Runde + 1
    continue
```

Comment: `for i in range(1):` - why? You don't even *use* `i`! Also note that `outcomes = print(...)` means `outcomes is None`; the print function doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue 1

```
>>> outcomes2 = ("Stein")
>>> print(random.choice(outcomes2))
n
```

You're iterating over a string and selecting a character at random.

I'm assuming you want:

```
>>> outcomes2 = ("Stein", )
>>> print(random.choice(outcomes2))
Stein
```

Now, by specifying the `,`, you're iterating over a tuple of strings (tuple of size 1). You'll end up getting "Stein" only unless you add more strings, like

```
outcomes2 = ("Stein", "Name2", "Name3", ...)
```

### Issue 2

You want `outcomes = random.choice(outcomes2)`. Do not assign the value to the `print` statement, because `print` returns None.

Putting it together...

```
outcomes2 = ("Stein", )

Runde = 0
while True:
    Player = input("Deine Wahl: ")
    outcomes = random.choice(outcomes2)

    if outcomes == Player:
       print("draw")
       Runde + 1
       continue
```

Comment: It would be helpful to explain why that comma makes a difference (or reference something that does).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I did mention that he would be iterating over a tuple  (ergo, `,` is the syntax for specifying a tuple). But you're right. For a beginner, that isn't much to go on. Edited.

Comment: Thank you very much, The main Issue was Issue 2, i also just realised that i was iterating over a string

Comment: @Forex After Issue 2, the main issue would've become Issue 1! Cheers, glad to help.

Answer (score -2):

```
`import time
import random
comp_score=0
play_score=0
outcome=('rock','paper','scissor')

while True:     
    player = raw_input("Enter any?");   
    out=random.choice(outcome) 
    print "COMP->"+out      
    if out==player:     
        print "draw"    
    elif out=="rock"and player=="scissor":      
    comp_score+=1;  
    elif out=="scissor" and player=="rock":     
        play_score+=1;  
    elif out=="rock" and player=="paper":   
        play_score+=1;  
    elif out=='paper' and player=='rock':   
        comp_score+=1;  
    elif out=="scissor" and player=="paper": 
            play_score+=1;  
    elif out=='paper' and player=="scissor":
            comp_score+=1;  
    elif player=="quit":        
    break; 
    print "GAME over"
    print "PLayer score: ",play_score
    print "Comp score ",comp_score`
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Also, you should probably format it as well.